# Proguard retrace missing line numbers

Tags: android, proguard

I'm trying to deobfucate a stack trace from my Android app.  I used proguard when building the app and running retrace seem to work, more or less.

What isn't working is decoding the line numbers.  No line numbers are shown on the output and it lists several choices for each "at".

Here is my proguard-project.txt file:

```
-keepattributes LineNumberTable
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static int v(...);
    public static int d(...);
}
```

This is my stack trace:

```
uncaught exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.ag.a(Unknown Source)
at com.myuapp.myapp.dbaccess.x.a(Unknown Source)
at com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.x.a(Unknown Source)
at com.myapp.myapp.main.ab.run(Unknown Source)
```

And here is the output:

```
uncaught exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.ZNodeCache.com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.ZNode getNodeFromCache(long)(Unknown Source)
                                             com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.ZRoot getRootFromCache()
                                             com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.ZNode getNodeFromDb(long,boolean)
                                             com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.ZNode$Array getChildrenForExport(com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.ZNode)
                                             ... many more ...
at com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.XmlImport.com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.XmlImport$Results importFile(java.lang.String)(Unknown Source)
                                            void _doImport(java.io.InputStream,com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.XmlImport$Results)
                                            void importFile(java.io.InputStream)
                                            void importNode(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.ZNode)
                                             ... many more ...
at com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.XmlImport.com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.XmlImport$Results importFile(java.lang.String)(Unknown Source)
                                            void _doImport(java.io.InputStream,com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.XmlImport$Results)
                                            void importFile(java.io.InputStream)
                                            void importNode(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.ZNode)
                                             ... many more ...
at com.myapp.myapp.main.MainActivity$3.void run()(Unknown Source)
```

I must be missing another configuration parameter; any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Turns out the answer is in the Android documentation (believe it or not).  I guess I missed it the first time around.  You need to specify the source file, like this:

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

The renamsesourcefileattribute will cause all source files to have the name SourceFile (or whatever you put).  "retrace" doesn't care what the source file name is, but if you leave it out, it decides to ignore the line numbers.

This goes in proguard-project.txt which, if you're using Android Studio, you'll find in "your project".app.

Comment: Your answer led me to http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#stacktrace which contains the additional line -printmapping out.map

Comment: In which file did you put these lines? I have tried it in `proguard-rules.pro` file in Android Studio but line numbers doesn't appear yet.

Comment: In proguard-project.txt

Comment: Does this make it any easier for someone trying to reverse-engineer your code?

Comment: @voxoid Same question here. So does anybody have an answer for this (after 4 years)?

Comment: @ch271828n You can install "jadx" and see the smali for yourself. I believe no because even without these proguard will still retain a RELATIVE line number information.