# Confusion reading Flurry's stack trace

Tags: android, flurry

I have an app on google play which has [flurry](http://www.flurry.com/flurry-analytics.html) diagnostics in. On the flurry website it reports a `NullPointerException` but I am struggling to work out what section of code it is occurring in.

The program is protected with proguard, but flurry has a system whereby you upload proguard's mapping.txt and it will translate.

The resulting "stack trace" is shown below. I am puzzled the fact that it says "Unknown Source" in relation to `set_up_text_trace_for_quiz`, and also by the list of five methods immediately below. Where has the null pointer exception occurred? And why does `add_game_play_buttons` have `$2548a35` next to it?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.mycompany.mygame.DEF_GamePlay.set_up_text_trace_for_quiz(Unknown Source)
                             start_up_game_mode
                             distxyxy
                             do_move
                             add_game_play_buttons$2548a35
                             tpl
com.mycompany.mygame.DEF_GamePlay$MicksSurfaceViewExtension.onTouchEvent(Unknown Source)
android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7340)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1928)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1928)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1928)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1928)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2113)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1466)
android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2468)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2061)
android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7525)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3368)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3300)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4392)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4370)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4474)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:163)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4442)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4493)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:523)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I have found flurry crash reporting to be woeful. I used to use it but had so many problems that I switched to Crashlytics which has been great. You might want to consider it if you are having the same experience with Flurry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the output, it is likely that your ProGuard configuration file is missing the following lines:

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Please take a look at [another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21079891/1023092) for some more details.

Comment: Your answer led me to proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#stacktrace which contains the additional line -printmapping out.map

Comment: Just got my first new flurry crash report with these new lines in proguard config (also with -printmapping out.map), and the stack trace now looks as it should.