# Function names in one class after obfuscation

Tags: java, android, proguard

I have several function in different "namespaces" (packages, classes or so) i.e.:

```
com.example.class1.foo1()
com.example.class1.foo2(string);
com.example.class1.foo3();
com.example.sth.class1.foo1();
com.example.sth.class2.foo1();
```

After obfuscation, with my current settings, I'm getting sth like:

```
com.example.a.a()
com.example.a.a(string) 
com.example.a.b()
com.example.sth.a.a()
com.example.sth.b.a()
```

It is all good except one thing: two `a` methods in `com.example.a`. Is there any way to tell proguard to give different names to different function inside one class?

Comment: What's the problem with that? The methods have a different signature, so they will work anyway.

Comment: What do you really want to achieve with this?

Comment: @FD_ From my diagnostics system I'm getting information about errors. There I don't have full signature, just function name. It is hard to debug if I have 15 methods `a`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to just disable ProGuard for debug builds?

Comment: @FD_ I'm talking about production builds. When I publish my application and it crashed I want to know where.

Comment: Ok, makes sense now ;)

Comment: The stack traces should still show the line number of the method that was called.

Comment: @kjkrum I'm not getting line number (maybe sth else is not configured properly). I'm getting sth like: `at com.example.a (Unknown source)`

Comment: Check out the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065998/proguard-retrace-missing-line-numbers (Took me two minutes to find that with Google...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper solution is to preserve debug information about line numbers:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

You could also let ProGuard use different names:

```
-useuniqueclassmembernames
```

but that doesn't avoid preexisting name overloading.